# Trouble during install phonegap version 3.0.0 in windows os 8

Tags: cordova, windows-8, cordova-3

Hi I need to install cordova version 3.0.0 in my Windows 8 system.

I already install and work with phone gap version 2.9.0

I try with following method for install cordova 3.0.0

**Step-1**:- Install node.js[v0.10.26] form http://nodejs.org/

**Step-2**:-  Open node.js command prompt Then i enter following command

```
 c:\Users\Pixel1 Window8> npm install -g cordova@3.0.0
```

After Run above command following result show

[image]

**Step-3**:-

```
 c:\Users\Pixel1 Window8>cordova create hello com.example.hello Helloworld
```

**Step-4**:-

```
  c:\Users\Pixel1 Window8>cd hello
```

**Step-5**:-

```
  c:\Users\Pixel1 Window8\hello>cordova platform add wp8
```

Following error occur in this command

[image]

How to solve this problem ?

I'm installing the cordova in correct way or not..?

Thank you

Comment: Check to see if you set the platform sdk set up correctly.You wont be able to add platform correctly if the set up is wrong.

Comment: How can i check setup is correctly installed?

Comment: Do you have visual studios for wp8?If you have android bundle just add platform android,if this is performed correctly means then there is a problem with your wp8 platform alone which is directly related to visual studio set up issue

Comment: Unable to add Android platform